# Как присвоить значение функции в html документе?

Tags: javascript

Во внешнем документе у меня есть функция.

> var class;
>
> function btn1( ) {
>         var elm = document.getElementById(class).style;
>
> ```
>      elm.display=((elm.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none');
> }
> ```

Задача данной функции менять значение стиля с display:none, на display:block и наоборот при нажатии на кнопку. 
Я вызвал данную функцию следующим образом:

```
<div onClick="btn1() сlass='p1'"></div>
```

Проблема вот в чем: мне надо присвоить переменной `class` значение `p1`, где `p1` название `id`, который будет менять функция. Если в самой функции сразу прописать вместо `class` имя `p1`, то функция прекрасно работает, но так как функция применяться должна многократно и в этой функции меняется только значение `getElementById(class)`, то проще всего это значение сделать переменной и присваивать ей нужное значение уже сразу в документе, но вот как это сделать, я не знаю.

Comment: чтобы код был виден есть три способа: 
4 пробела
обратный слэш перед экранируемым символом
MYSQLевские кавычки \`

Comment: Повтор [вопроса](http://hashcode.ru/questions/126487/кнопка-срабатывает-со-второго-клика-а-должна-с-первого-как-устранить? "Кнопка срабатывает со второго клика, а должна с первого, как устранить?")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function btn1(class) { 
    var elm = document.getElementById(class).style;

     elm.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
<div onClick="btn1('p1')" ></div>
```

не?...

Comment: cупер все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Слушайте, заюзайте jQuery! Там почти все возможные проблемы отпадут сами собой, да и код сократится в разы. Так, например, это:

```
  Задача данной функции менять значение стиля с display:none, на display:block и наоборот при нажатии на кнопку. Я вызвал данную функцию следующим образом: (<)div onClick="btn1() сlass='p1' "(>)(<)/div(>)
```

Можно сделать вызовом одной функции - `toggle(func1,func2,...)`

Comment: Вы тоже не умеете экранировать сиволы? Или это стеб над автором?

Comment: В любом случае + за ответ, ибо jquery. :) И за рекомендацию отделить мух от котлет, то есть, представление от логики этого представления.